# Is there a webpack file loader for .node files?

Tags: webpack, electron

I try to use diskusage (https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskusage) in my electron webpack setup.

The build process errors with:

```
...\node_modules\diskusage\build\Release\diskusage.node Unexpected character '?'. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a webpack loader for .node files called name [node-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-loader)